# Evaluate $\int\frac{3x+\sqrt{x-1}}{x-2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I've tried to solve this and made several simplifications, yet my answer does not match the correct one. Can anyone point out where I've messed up in the calculations?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your error is integrating $\frac{1}{t^2-1}$ as $\frac12\ln|t^2-1|+C$. You want to integrate $\frac12\left(\frac{1}{t-1}-\frac{1}{t+1}\right)$, giving $\frac12\ln\left|\frac{t-1}{t+1}\right|+C$.

Comment: Thanks! I got the right answer by fixing that

Answer (score 0):

The substitution is fine. Then you got $\dfrac{2 t \left(3 t^2+t+3\right)}{t^2-1}$, which is equal to $2\left(3t+1+\dfrac{6t+1}{t^2-1}\right)$. Up to this point, I agree. But$$\int\frac{6t+1}{t^2-1}\,\mathrm dt=\int\frac{5}{2 (t+1)}-\frac{7}{2 (1-t)}\,\mathrm dt=\frac52\log\lvert t+1\rvert+\frac72\log\lvert t-1\rvert.$$